# What is the equivalent of the retired mvn eclipse:eclipse in m2e?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The [Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is retired. What is the equivalent command line or in Eclipse UI for:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

that generates the files that a project requires to be seen as a Java project in Eclipse?

Comment: Generally you simply import the project as a Maven project inside Eclipse.

Comment: You can import an existing Maven project in your workspace via the Import procedure (Import as Existig Maven Projects), this would configure Eclipse via the proper files (and Java nature). Otherwise, if the project was already imported in Eclipse but not as a Maven project, you would go through a double clik on concerned project > Configure > Convert to Maven project, which would configure Eclipse properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `eclipse` goal of the `maven-eclipse-plugin` would [actually](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/):

> generates the Eclipse configuration files.

Which basically means `.project`, `.classpath` and the `.settings` folder.

These folders and procedure is handled by the `Import` action, where you can actually specify to import an existing project as a Maven project:

[image]

Right click on the Projects view > `Import` > `Import..`. The procedure will properly create the aforementioned files and configure Eclipse accordingly.

However, shall you already have the project imported (in that case files would already exist), you can convert the existing project to Maven via the `Configure` action:

[image]

A right click on the concerned project > `Configure` > `Convert to Maven Nature` would then modify the existing files and settings to recognize the Maven build (mostly adding the `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature` nature and `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder` information to the existing `.project` file).

Comment: `maven-eclipse-plugin` is retired also, is there any alternative from the command line?

Comment: nope, as specified by its official page, the IDE integration is recommended, hence via UI, not command line. Why do you still need to interact between your maven project and Eclipse via command line?

Comment: just out of curiosity, `eclipse:eclipse` is very useful, it makes no sense to retire it, I thought there was a better alternative.