# How to do the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` through the M2Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

It came to my attention that:

The maven-eclipse-plugin (used in `mvn eclipse:eclipse`) is discontinued and shouldn't be used anymore. M2Eclipse replaces it for most, if not all, usage.

I work on a new project now, and the M2Eclipse doesn't update automatically the changes in my eclipse project.

My question is:

How to do the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` through the M2Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the retired mvn eclipse:eclipse in m2e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523575/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-retired-mvn-eclipseeclipse-in-m2e)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's equivalent **Import an existing Maven Project**. Elipse will do rest of the things. You might need to change your project to maven type.

```
Configure>Convert to Maven Project
```