# Running mvn eclipse:eclipse and the build path

Tags: eclipse, maven

Apologies if this is a simple question...

When I run the mvn eclipse:eclipse command to resolve the classpaths for eclipse it always appends the projects version as well.   So if the project is called "ATestProject" and the version is "3", the build path will look for "ATestProject-3" but eclipse knows it only as "ATestProject".  So there is a error unless I manually add the "ATestProject".

Is there a way to exclude the version?  OR am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Do NOT use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. The [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is retired and not maintained. Use [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), which is the Eclipse plugin integration Maven in Eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the retired mvn eclipse:eclipse in m2e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523575/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-retired-mvn-eclipseeclipse-in-m2e)