# Project 'X' is missing required source folder: 'target/generated-resources/eclipse'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

Java build path problem in Eclipse :

Project 'X' is missing required source folder: 'target/generated-resources/eclipse'

Also I have this "Errors running builder "Integrated External Tool Builder" on project X" when building project. It s a program configuration defined in "Builders" on project to run `eclipse:eclipse` (in properties).

Comment: Have `m2e` plugin installed? Maven update project?

Comment: Yes of cources and when building the project I have this error "Errors during build. Errors running builder "Integrated External Tool Builder" on project X".

Comment: It might help a lot if you edited those errors/stack trace to the question. So the stack / details of the error, you need to find them. What would be that `External tool builder`? Guess it is responsible creating & populating missing folder then?

Comment: It s a program configuration defined in the section "Builders" (in
 properties).

Comment: These days use "m2e-apt" instead of eclipse:eclipse.  This works much better for apt generated sources in modern versions of Eclipse.  See https://github.com/ravn/dagger2-hello-world for a small complete example.

Comment: Thank you @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. No need to run eclipse:eclipse on the project. We just need to import it as a maven external project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to import the project as a existing maven project in eclipse without launching the goal eclispe:eclispe because the Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin is retired (see comments above).

For more explanation and details :

See [What is the equivalent of the retired mvn eclipse:eclipse in m2e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523575/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-retired-mvn-eclipseeclipse-in-m2e)

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/